# Comando SDK Facebook Android - Hash de chave

Tags: android, facebook, hash

Estou fazendo o tutorial do [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) do *Facebook* para *Android* e não entendi essa parte, que fala sobre `hashes` de chave para ambientes de desenvolvimento.

[image: Print do Tutorial]

Comando:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64`

Onde devo executar esse comando? Tentei CMD mas deu erro.

Comment: Qual erro ocorreu ?

Comment: "'keytool' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olá, você deve informar o caminho onde está o keytool e o openssl no seu computador. No meu caso está em:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\keytool.exe

C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe

agora é só substituir, ficará assim:

**"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\keytool.exe"**-exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | **"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe"** sha1 -binary | **"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe"** base64

Feito isso, você precisa informar uma senha, que por padrão é **android**.

Pronto! Vai aparecer sua hash, vc deve copiar tudo incluindo o **=**

Answer (score 9):

Existem milhões de formas de recuperar essa Key Hash.

Ela serve para identificar que somente o seu projeto está acessando as informações do Facebook do usuário, como forma de segurança mesmo.

Eu sempre quebrava a cabeça pra recuperar essa key, mas aprendi uma forma bem simples de ser feita.

Dentro do método onCreate, coloque esse código:

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                           getPackageName(),
                           PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Agora rode a sua aplicação, no seu LogCat (Android Monitor), irá aparecer um código mais ou menos assim:

```
KeyHash: nzM5O1NWEmtflcC3vDK2lx3CwcM=
```

Todos esses números e letras são a sua Hash Key, inclusive o sinal de **=**, ai você coloca la no painel de controle do Facebook, pra que ele reconheça sua apliacação.

Comment: Lembrando que esse método só serve para o procedimento de Debug , ou seja, desenvolvimento. Correto ?